# Python error generating PDF from recursive directories

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python and I'm trying to learn from books and the internet.

I have about 250 subfolders with jpg, and i'm trying to make a pdf file for each folder.

Folders are like this

```
c:\img_sets\001
c:\img_sets\002
.
.
c:\img_sets\247
```

I want to PDF like this

```
c:\img_sets\001.pdf
c:\img_sets\002.pdf
.
.
c:\img_sets\247.pdf
```

I run the script from c:\img_sets (windows 10 and python 3.6)

Here is "the code", just added 2 prints out with the files list, just for control.

```
from fpdf import FPDF
import os
pdf = FPDF()
rootDir = '.'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
    for namedir in dirs:
        imagelist = [name for name in os.listdir(namedir) if name.endswith(".jpg")]
        for image in imagelist:
            print(namedir + "\\" + image)
            pdf.add_page()
            pdf.image(namedir + "\\" + image,0,0,210,297)
        print(namedir + ".pdf")
        pdf.output(namedir + ".pdf", "F")
```

This create the first one, but the second shows me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python\Python36-32\jpg2pdf_v2.py", line 13, in <module>
pdf.output(namedir + ".pdf", "F")
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 1065, in output
    self.close()
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 246, in close
    self._enddoc()
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 1637, in _enddoc
    self._putresources()
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 1585, in _putresources
    self._putimages()
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 1515, in _putimages
    del info['data']
KeyError: 'data'
```

All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

found the error. pdf = FPDF() was wrong was outside loop.

```
import fpdf
import os
rootDir = '.'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
    for dir in dirs:
        print(os.path.join(root, dir))
        imagelist = [name for name in os.listdir(os.path.join(root, dir)) if name.endswith(".jpg")]
        print(imagelist)
        pdf = fpdf.FPDF()
        for image in imagelist:
            pdf.add_page()
            pdf.image(rootDir + dir + "\\" + image, 0, 0, 210, 297)
        pdf.output(rootDir + dir + ".pdf", "F")
```